# Postgresql Drop Table If exists

Tags: database, postgresql, function, exception

I Work with Postgresql and I want to drop Table if exists .My code is

```
execute 'drop table if exists production.'|| layer_name || '' into result_var;
exception 
    when others then 
    execute 'insert into production.'|| layer_name || ' select * from staging.'|| layer_name ;
return 1;
```

but table if not exists thows exeption .I do not want to trow exeption

Can anybody help me?

Comment: As Daniel mentions, the "WHEN OTHERS" block is hiding the error. If you are going to use that catch-all, it is usually helpful to emit the error message using `SQLERRM` or `GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS

Answer (score 3):

`DROP TABLE` does not return any row, so the `INTO` clause must not be used.

Also, don't use `WHEN OTHERS` in an exception block that eats any error whatever it is.
It's frustrating both for debugging and troubleshooting problems later when the code is deployed.

If it wasn't for this clause, you'd had the error message saying why it doesn't work.